# C++ Read txt file and append data in each line

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream, ofstream

I want to open a file, and in each line append a string in the end.

I have this code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//argv[1] input file 
//argv[2] string to add in the end of each line
//argv[3] output file
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  ifstream open_file(argv[1]);
  if (!open_file) {
      std::cerr << "Could not open input file\n";
      return 0;
  } 
  ofstream new_file(argv[3]);
  if (!new_file) {
     std::cerr << "Could not create output file\n";
     return 0;
  } 
  string s = argv[2];
  string str;
  while (getline(open_file, str)) {
     new_file << str << s << "\n";
  }
}
```

The thing is the string is not adding in the end of each line. It is creating a new line for each string trying to be appended.

So I run for example: ./appendstring.e wordlist.txt hello new_wordlist.txt

and this is the output:

[image]

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a hint: Read the file and `push_back()` each line to an `std::vector<std::string>`, then append to each line the text you want. Finally, write all lines back to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your first file contains \r\n sequences for End of Line..

You may have to remove the `\r` character that is already in your first file, because you are reading in the string with the `\r` on the end.

Trim the `\r` off the end of `str`, before you use this line of code:

```
new_file << str << s << "\n";
```

See here
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: Fixed! Thanks a lot. You were right.
All I did was adding: 
    str.erase(str.size() - 1);

Comment: Glad it helped.  Welcome to Stackoverflow :)